# Rails I18N Nested Interpoliation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to nest interpolation in a translation (similar to how Ruby's string interpolation works)? The syntax I'd like is something like:

```
en:
  welcome: "Welcome %{user.name} from %{user.location.name}"
```

Then:

```
t(:welcome, user: user)
```

**Note:** I realize this can be done by specifying two separate keys but my example is a bit more complicated and would be easily solved if I could do something like the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the format you're looking for is supported. Lines 6-8 show no regex that matches your pattern.

https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb#L6